# UV Wavelengths Sparkd

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

What UV wavelengths are contained in orange electrical discharge sparks?
If the sparks are produced from the slight burning of Teflon covered steel conductor does that alter the uv light frequencies?

Comment: Usually sparks in air are blueish white, the nitrogen in the air does produce some UV. I think if you are seeing orange perhaps it is the insulation or you also have some burning. When stuff burns you can also produce small amounts of UV.  Can't say much more without more details of the setup.

Comment: If the sparks arose from bridging or shorting a 12v car battery what uv wavelengths would be emitted or is it impossible to say?

Comment: What factors does it depend on?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a spark in air you get an emission spectrum that will look something like this.

[image: Spark discharge in air]

So you see a emission from the nitrogen and oxygen atoms. You can see that there is some UV from in the 300-400 mainly from the nitrogen.

If you have a car battery, you have pretty low voltage and can have a lot of current, and it can be dangerous so I don't recommend experimenting. But it is can be a little more complicated because in addition to the air being ionized you may have some ionization of the metal electrodes. Basically after the spark hits the metal and vaporizes the little pit, the metal that was in the pit has been turned into a plasma, melted and ejected, If you looked at the light you would see a bunch of atomic emission lines that would depend on the metal, and some emission lines from the air.

So it is hard to say. But it is probably not an efficient way to produce a lot UV.

There are companies that make Spark optical emission spectrometers, because when the spark turns the little bit of metal into a plasma, you can capture the light from the plasma and tell what kind of metals are in the sample.
Rather than a car battery, they will usually have a high voltage source.

In general the ability to produce a spark in air will depend on the voltage, higher better, and distance between electrodes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137445/discussion-on-answer-by-uvphoton-uv-wavelengths-sparkd). @Student44 If you have further questions, please ask them as new questions; this is not a forum for back and forth discussion.