# How are electric sparks produced?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, lightning

Here's what I have understood so far.

(Im talking about electric spark we see in a gas lighter,as shown in the picture)

[image]

When high voltage is generated at the central metal piece, electrons fly off the metal due to high electric field produced. These electrons strike the air molecules and make them loose their electrons as well, and a sort of chain reaction causes more and more electrons to be produced which flow along the electric field, meanwhile ions are being produced. After sometime, the ions reattach to ions again.

Firstly, How correct is the explanation? What critical points am I missing?

Secondally, How is the light produced by the spark? Is it the thermal radiation from atoms and ions? or is it the electromagnetic waves produced by moving and accelerating charges?

Comment: The phenomenon you're looking for is [dielectric breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown)

Comment: Thans g s. I read that article. I was just wondering if my understanding is correct about it (because i often underrstand things incorrectly). Here, Im mainly concerned with the light that is produced in a spark.

Comment: Mix of thermal radiation and characteristic radiation from the de-excitation of the nitrogen/oxygen plasma. I don't know what the proportion is. Electron beams in vacuum do emit a faint glow from accelerated charges, but I don't think that light is a significant contribution. Someone may be able to provide a more confident answer.

Comment: The spectrum of light produced by a spark in air is (for several days only) right here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5143/79678. It is a figure in R. Walker’s 34 page document, referenced below the figure. The document is freely available online. The spark shown in the photo you posted looks rather violet, as expected from the spectrum: the excited nitrogen atoms are emitting in the violet and blue spectral region.

Comment: See the answer, with spectrum, here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/715827/313612.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is basically correct for the *avalanche* and *extinction*, but things start off a little differently, as follows.

We first apply a strong electric field between the electrodes. Now we have a force which will tend to pull electrons off of the negative electrode and propel them towards the positive electrode. If that field is sufficiently strong, then electrons do get pulled off and *field emission* takes place. Then the avalanche builds, the air stops being an insulator, and a *power arc* results between the electrodes. the current flowing through the conductive air heats it up very suddenly, and light is emitted from the tiny thread of very very hot air.

Certain wavelengths of light predominate; these are associated with the recombination of electrons with the ionized air molecules (nitrogen and oxygen).

If that field is not quite strong enough to trigger field emission, then the system sits in a metastable state until a random ultraviolet photon happens along and collides with the negative electrode. This triggers a tiny amount of *photoemission* where one electron gets knocked out of the electrode surface and accelerates away under the influence of the field, thereby triggering the avalanche effect.